# Allocate memory dynamically

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Let's say I want to create an array of strings

```
char** array=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*1);
//option 1
array[0]=malloc(strlen(string)); array[0]=string;
//option 2
array[0]=string;
```

What's the correct way of doing that and why?

I was thinking that 1st option is fine, but [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) says that it's causing a memory leak and therefore should be freed. But if I don't allocate memory for the string, then it becomes a local variable and then will be destroyed right after the end of the function? Then why do both options work? And if the 1st option is correct, then how should I free the memory in order to stop the leakage?

Comment: It depends where `string` is allocated in the first place and whether you wish to store a copy of it or just the pointer to it. Your first option is a memory leak, the second stores a pointer. If you want to store a copy use the first option to allocate memory then `strcpy` to copy the data, or `strdup` which allocates and copies at the same time. With the second statement your string will change if it is changed by anyone else with access to that memory, and if that memory is freed then accessing it becomes undefined behavior.

Comment: You didn't do option 1 correctly.  You allocate storage, then you immediately discard it, replacing the pointer with `string`.  So it's equivalent to option 2, except you have a memory leak.

Comment: You should not need to cast the malloc return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In option 1

```
array[0]=malloc(strlen(string)); // need +1 see below
array[0]=string;
```

you set `array[0]` to a new allocated area by *malloc*, then you replace `array[0]` value with `string`, thus the initial allocated address is lost, and *valgrind* tells you that. You could do

```
array[0]=malloc(strlen(string)+1); // +1 for trailing 0
strcpy(array[0], string);          // copy string into array[0]
... 
free (array[0]); // when you are done working with array[0]
free (array);    // when you are done working with array
```

Option 2

```
array[0]=string;
```

is fine. `array[0]` characters may be modified or not depending on how `string` was created.